# Google app engine swf file not loading

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, flash

I'm having some problems trying to load a SWF file to embed a flash video on my website. The website has been deployed through Google App Engine (PHP runtime). The flash move appears to be there, but it is just a white screen. When you right-click it, it says 'Movie not loaded...'

I've tried a couple of methods, each of which ended up with the same result. Source code can be seen through these URLs.

http://www.andrewrgoss.com/iidfinalproject.html

http://www.andrewrgoss.com/iidfinalproject2.html

I did make sure to add .swf extension to my app.yaml file, as you can see below. The .swf file exists in the same directory as the .html files. Any ideas why I can't get this to work? Additionally, is there a better (ideally relatively simple) alternative approach that could be used here?

```
application: andrewrgoss
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
# All URLs beginning with /stylesheets are treated as paths to static files in
# the stylesheets/ directory.

- url: /images\.ico
 static_files: images/db_favicon.ico
 upload: images/db_favicon\.ico

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf))
 static_files: \1
 upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf))

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file "http://www.andrewrgoss.com/AGoss_IID_FinalProject8282011.swf" is returning a 404.

It appears the file you're after is "http://www.andrewrgoss.com/web/AGoss_IID_FinalProject8282011.swf" - probably it's contained in a subdirectory named "web" in your project?

Comment: Yikes! Got hung up on thinking I was doing something else wrong, not referencing the wrong file location. That's why it pays to have another set of eyes. Thanks for the help.